how to bulk export bryton .fit files?
I have a Bryton Rider410 GPS. I periodically connect it to my linux computer with USB and download the .FIT files before emptying the device (otherwise the android app gets really slow). I have just discovered that I appear not to have done this for a particular 6 month period a couple of years ago.
The Bryton android app is configured to auto-upload ("sync") to their system when I connect the device. All the relevant ride data is visible on their website (active.brytonsport.com) as well as in the app.
I see no way to export data from the website.
The android app has an "Export Fit File" option for each ride, so  if I really had to, it appears I could export each ride individually from the android app but this would be very time-consuming and tedious.
Is there a way to bulk export all (or a range of) data rather than one ride at a time?

in the end I did the time-consuming manual export while watching a tv program...
